# What's the meaning of "!", "?", "_", and "." syntax in elixir

Tags: elixir

I need help regarding understanding the following syntaxes in elixir `!`, `?`, `_`, and `.`. 
What's those syntaxes role in elixir's function? For example `Repo.get!`.

I'm not sure whether they were just function name, or has a role. Though I know `.` is for calling anonymous function. And `_` for any or variadic?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`!` - Convention for functions which raise exceptions on failure.

`?` - Convention for functions which return a boolean value

`_` - Used to ignore an argument or part of a pattern match expression.

`.` - As you mentioned is used for calling an anonymous function, but is also used for accessing a module function such as `Mod.a(arg)`.

Comment: There does exist an important difference between variables that *start with* the `_` (such as `_foobar`) and those that *consist only* of `_` (such as `def foo(_, _bar) do, _bar end`). Attempts to use the `_` result in compile time 'unbound variable' errors.  Variables prefixed with an underscore, `_bar`, serve to prevent warnings for unused variables, and will not prevent compilation. Their use only generates a warning: "warning: the underscored variable "_bar" is used after being set. A leading underscore indicates that the value of the variable should be ignored..."

Comment: is there any reason is_integer doesn't have a question mark ? - https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#is_integer/1 @Marc

Answer (score 17):

Firstly **!** and **?**

They are naming conventions usually applied to the end of function name and are **not** any special syntax.

**!** - Will raise an exception if the function encounters an error.

One good example is [Enum.fetch!](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#fetch!/2)(It also has a same [Enum.fetch](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#fetch/2) which does not raise exception).Finds the element at the given index (zero-based).
Raises OutOfBoundsError if the given position is outside the range of the collection.

**?** - Used to show that the function will return a boolean value, either true or false. One good example is [Enum.any?](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#any?/2) that returns true if functions is true for any value, otherwise return false

`_`  -  This will ignore an argument in function or in pattern matching. If you like you can give a name after underscore.Ex - *_base*

This is commonly used in the end of a tail recursive function.  One good example is the power function. If you want to raise any number base to 0 the result it 1, so it really does not matter what base is

```
defp getPower(_base,0), do: 1
```

`.` - Used to access any function inside the module or as you suggested calling an anonymous function

```
iex(1)> square = fn(number) -> number * number end
iex(2)> square.(4)
```

Comment: Just a note: the `getPower` function can make use of pattern matching: `defp getPower(_base, 0), do: 1`